# Why do I get "Expected Statement" error even though I ended my if statement?

Tags: vbscript

It's supposed to be a simple script for renaming files in a current directory.
I get this error

[image: Error]

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder(".\")

For Each File In Folder.Files
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile,"apt sth-sth2-sth3","apt curr1_curr2_curr3")
    if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
    end if
Next
```

Comment: Try putting the statement on its own line, so that “then” is the last word on the if statements line. See https://www.guru99.com/vbscript-conditional-statements.html

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the correct answers: the syntax in BASIC for an `If` statement can be varied as follows:

1) If with a **single** statement:

```
If <condition> Then <statement>
```

e.g.

```
If (sNewFile<>File.Name) Then File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
```

Note the missing closing `End If`. And the whole construct must be on **one** line.

2) If with **one or more** statements:

```
If <condition> Then
   <statement>
   [<statement>]
   [...]
   [<statement>]
End If
```

e.g.

```
If (sNewFile<>File.Name) Then 
    File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
End If
```

As the latter also works for cases with just a single statement, I made myself a habit of always using the `If/End IF` syntax. Just as you came up as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, my hypothesis was correct. Adding it here for completeness.

The content of the if statement must be on its own line, like this:

```
if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then 
    File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
end if
```

Comment: Not entirely true as the other answer explains. You just needed to remove the `End If`.